# JMeter: JSON Response body assertion

Tags: json, jmeter, assertion

These are the sample responses for my API request

Sample 1: {
"success": [{
"requestKey": "dac105de-2a1b-49a4-92d8-fce4462bbe4c",
"externalKey": "0",
"person": {
"ID": "PAU1772881848"
},
"business": {
"ID": "BAU0264699094"
}
}],
"error": []
}

Sample 2:
{
"success": [{
"requestKey": "d2e500b3-ce1d-41b6-bf8c-a1e337b436fe",
"externalKey": "0",
"person": {
"ID": "PAU0917783377"
},
"business": {
"ID": "BAU0152754693"
}
}],
"error": [{
"requestedUri": null,
"requestKey": "fe9e7858-009d-4e10-8ba6-8b6d18666f7e",
"errorCode": "BusinessPhoneNumberNotUnique",
"errorMessage": "This phone number is already registered"
}]
}

I would like to add an assertion to check if the response body contains any errors. What's the best way to do it in JMeter? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JMeter Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) in order to conditionally mark samplers as failed basing on various criteria

For particular your case the most suitable option is [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) which allows execution of arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries and validate their output values, given your examples I think you need to check that the length of `error` [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) is equal to `0`

Relevant JSON Assertion configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. its exactly what I was looking for..